# Как создать субдомен с именем пользователя в качестве имени поддомена?

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess

Здравствуйте!
Задача такая...после регистрация у пользователя создается уникальный юзернейм...
и нужно при выход к свои кабинете в даресному строку должно отображать так

например юзернейм: dilik

а адрес должно быт так в кабинете: dilik.site.com

помогите если вы знаете как решать этот задачу...что нужно сделать? в хостинге придётся что-нибудь изменить? или можно с htaccess ом решать все?

Comment: Боюсь это не тривиальное решение на уровне конфигов web-сервера.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Определить доступность субдоменов - доходят ли запросы к серверу или хостингу (далее сервер).**

Есть два варианта открыть все субдомены и они будут доступны (проще), либо добавлять по одному автоматически.
Если автоматически то или иметь свой dns сервер, или использовать api (если оно есть) где хостится домен.

1.1.Для проверки доступности, используем старый добрый ping:

[image: PING DOMAIN]

1. Не доступен суб домен qqw.google.com.
2. Доступный хост google.com по ip 172.217.16.14.
3. Доступный субдомен maps.google.com по ip 172.217.16.14.
4. Подтверждение того, что запрос приходит на одни сервер (172.217.16.14).

1.2.В случае отсутствия доступа к хосту это делается через биллинг (админку) домена. Добавляется запись типа "A".
Например, для биллинга на базе Ispmgr записи будут выглядеть так:
[image: Ispmgr поддомен запись типа "A"]

1. Для всех поддомене (*.site.com), включая dilik.site.com, в случае отсутствие отдельной записи для этого хоста.
2. отдельно для dilik.site.com.

**2. Настройка конфига для веб-сервер.**

2.1.Nginx:

```
 server {
        listen       172.217.16.14:80;
        server_name  site.com *.site.com;

        charset utf8;

        location / {
            # Proxy user domains to /users/$username
            if ($host ~* "^(([a-z0-9_\-]+)\.site\.com)$") {
                set $uid $2;
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /users/$uid$1 break;
            }

        ...
```

2.2. Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName site.com
  ServerAlias *.site.com
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*) [nocase]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com$1 [redirect=permanent,nocase,last]
  </IfModule>
```

...

2.3. В случае отсутствия возможности править конфиги обращаться к хостингу.

**3. Обработка запроса yii2.**

3.1. Прописать правила роутинга (urlManager).

3.2. Не забыть поставить в контроллере проверка на валидность.